# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.Window.getDecorView()'

Tags: android, android-appcompat, android-preferences, preferenceactivity

I updated the version of the `androidx.appcompat:appcompat`to `1.1.0-alpha03` from `1.1.0-alpha02`. And after that my application started crashing in line `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`.
It happens in a class that extends `PreferenceActivity`. Any solutions ?

Comment: Exactly same issue here, i've to rollback to 1.1.0-alpha02 to understand the issue.

Comment: @tryp check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in new version (**1.1.0-alpha04**) of Appcompat.

```
implementation "androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha04"
```